# ODOO v10: How to display data from 2 models in 1 treeview?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, treeview, odoo-10

There are 2 tables:

1. submission (the one that I created for my module)
2. res_users (the one that odoo already has)

I have to display a treeview with data from these 2 models. I have an ID from res_users that is in my submission table, in order to differentiate between records. I need my treeview to display data for example:

**display all information from res_users and submission
where submission_id = res_user_id**

Help! since i'm very very new to odoo.

Comment: Please paste your code so we can understand your question.

Comment: Create a computed `One2Many` field.